# How can I fix TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, list, input, integer, numbers

How can I fix TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?

```
N = list(input("Enter long number: "))

Even = []
Odd = []

for i in list (N):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        Even.count (i)
    elif i % 2 == 1:
        Odd.count (i)

print (f"Even: {Even}")
print (f"Odd: {Odd}")
```

Comment: What are you expecting from the input? Is the list meant to split the number and iterate through every element in it?

Comment: I need to put the number for ex. 456789 and make seperate list of even (4,6,8) and odd (5,7,9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this?

```
N = list(input("Enter long number: "))

Even = []
Odd = []

for i in N:
    i = int(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        Even.append(i)
    elif i % 2 == 1:
        Odd.append(i)

print (f"Even: {Even}")
print (f"Odd: {Odd}")
```

Comment: this part is redundant, it is already a list: `list(N)`, also per PEP8 naming convention for variable and function names is `snake_case`

Comment: @grigoltsertsvadze replace `for i in list (N):` with `for i in N:`

Comment: @Matiiss it's not working

Comment: @grigoltsertsvadze yes, it is working, I don't know how you could mess up such a simple replacement but it is working (I mean maybe you use some python2 version but on python3 which you should use it works)

Comment: @Matiiss sorry, everything is good !!!